# What would be the equivalent elastic search query to this SQL query? I am trying to learn how to translate SQL to elasticsearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch

Select AVG(Salary)
FROM employee_table
WHERE Jobtitle = "Webmaster" and city = "dallas" or state = "california"

```
This is what I have but it did not return a result at all 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "Jobtitle": "Webmaster"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "state": "California",
            
          }
          
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "city": "Dallas"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My elasticsearch is setup to have an index: "salaries" and the fields below

ID

Jobtitle

city

salary

state

JSON Example
{
"_id": "gyfnLoQBy_hOUOvqeY9L",
"_index": "other",
"_score": 3.7432575,
"_source": {
"ID": "16",
"JobTitle": "Webmaster",
"city": "Dallas",
"salary": "89919.2314721147",
"state": "California"
}
},

Comment: Please share your mappings and check you post the request to the right endpoint...

Comment: @LeBigCat, okay I included that above, also I was just testing this out using elastic search dev tools query editor

Comment: @Gabs__1111 Can you please post index mapping. You can get index mapping by executing `GET salaries` from kibana dev tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregations to summarize your data as metrics, statistics, or other analytics.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "Jobtitle": "Webmaster"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "state": "California",
            
          }
          
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "city": "Dallas"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  aggs: {
    "avg_salary": { "avg": { "field": "salary" } }
  }
}
```

I think this may work.